# Bootstrap 4 browser support version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, browser, version, bootstrap-4

I am working on a new website and plan to use Bootstrap 4. Since its still in alpha stage, it is somewhat risky. [Bootstrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#supported-browsers) mentions that all the latest browsers are supported but does not specify from which version on.

So is it possible to know that from which browser version is bootstrap 4 supported?

Comment: Because this seems to be in the first results on google searches, and I was also looking for the same information (which I eventually found), I've added an answer for everyone's convenience.

Comment: Look at this  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From bootstrap web site,

> > Bootstrap supports the latest, stable releases of all major browsers and platforms. On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 10-11 / Microsoft Edge.

They mentioned all stable major releases are supported. With supporting ESR versions. Im not so sure but they meant by it, that currently latest browser versions and all future versions could handle bootstrap 4 as it should be.

Comment: Yes. But I need to know which earlier browser versions are supporting Bootstrap 4, especially mobile browsers.

Comment: Hi, they hasn't mentioned it clearly. but just an idea, you can check browser versions when they released bootstrap 4 alpha. (Ex- if the release date is Feb 1st, you can check latest versions of browsers at feb 1st.)
hope this helps

Comment: You can see details here: 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Answer (score 11):

The list of supported browsers can be found in the "package.json" file once you download bootstrap. It's also written on the bootstrap website in the documentation.
Here's the list of supported browsers for v4:

```
Chrome 45+
Firefox 38+
Opera 30+
Internet Explorer 10+
Edge 12+
iOS 9+
Safari 9+
Android 4.4+
```

Comment: As at 18 avril 2020, based on statistic information from statcounter.com on usage of browser versions, I calculate that 96.9% of users will be able to navigate a bootstrap 4 website. If Yandex browser 20.2 and 20.3 are compatible, it adds 1.2%, thus making a 98.0% compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Supported Browsers are:

```
"last 1 major version",
  ">= 1%",
  "Chrome >= 45",
  "Firefox >= 38",
  "Edge >= 12",
  "Explorer >= 10",
  "iOS >= 9",
  "Safari >= 9",
  "Android >= 4.4",
  "Opera >= 30"
```

Please refer to following URL for Supported Browsers:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/browsers-devices/

While latest release versions can be found at following: 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases